# How to take values ​from several checkboxes if one checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript

I have a checkbox, one in the table, and one outside the table (check all). The checkbox outside the table serves to check all the checkboxes on each row in the table and take the value checkbox and enter it in the textbox.  I have created a function to check all checkboxes in the table if the checkbox outside the table has been checked. The problem is that I can't retrieve all the checkbox values ​​and enter it to the textbox. How to take all the value checkboxes if the checkbox outside the table has been checked?
below is my view

```
<div id="sectionTable">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_all" onclick="paymentCheckedAll(this);" /><span>Check All</span>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>selected</th>
      <th>Name</th>                          
    </tr>
    @foreach (Learning.ViewModels.StudentViewModelitem in Model.StudentDetails)
    { 
      <tr>
        <td>
           @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelitem => item.IsChecked, new {@class = "idRow", @id = "test", @value="123" })           
        <td>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Name)
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
</table>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ListSelectedIdPayment)

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on(' change', 'input[name="check_all"]', function () {
            $('.idRow').prop("checked", this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide the function where you set the value?

Comment: I set the static value in the checkbox, the value is 123 @P.B.UDAY

Answer (score 0):

If you want values of all the checked checkboxes:

```
$('.idRow').each(function(){

 if($(this).attr('checked')){
     //set value here by $(this).attr('value')
  }
});
```